# How to Upload a file using Openload.co API

Tags: python, rest, api, multipartform-data

I'm trying to [upload a file](https://openload.co/api#upload) called '240p.mp4' with the Openload REST API.

Since Upload endpoint requires an SHA-1 Hash of the file, I got it by doing:

```
sha1 = hashlib.sha1()

BLOCKSIZE = 65536
with open('240p.mp4', 'rb') as afile:
    buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
    while len(buf) > 0:
        sha1.update(buf)
        buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)

sha1_hash = sha1.hexdigest()
```

So I requested an Upload link:

```
url = "https://api.openload.co/1/file/ul?login={login}&key={key}&sha1={sha1}".format(
    login='YOUR_LOGIN',
    key='YOUR_API_KEY',
    sha1=sha1_hash,
)

p = {
    'url': url,
    'headers': {
        'User-Agent': self.ua,
    }
}
r = self.r.get(url=p['url'], headers=p['headers'])
j = r.json()

upload_link = j['result']['url']
```

They suggest to make a **CURL** But I'm more of a `requests` guy ^^

```
curl -F file1=@/path/to/file.txt https://13abc37.example.com/ul/jAZUhVzeU78
```

So I tried to replicate it with a POST Request:

```
p = {
    'url': upload_link,
    'headers': {
        'user-agent': self.ua,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary="xxx"',
    },
    'files': {
        'file1': open('/scripts/wordpress/240p.mp4', "rb"),
      # I've also tried this (and some others)
      # 'file1': ('240.mp4', open('/scripts/wordpress/240p.mp4', "rb"), 'video/mp4')
    }
}
r = self.r.post(url=p['url'], headers=p['headers'], files=p['files'])
```

But it returns this error response:

```
r.content¬
{
    "status": 500,
    "msg": "failed to read: closed"
}
```

In theory, the status 500 errors are errors from the server. But why I'm getting this error ?

**N1:** I've set `boundary="xxx"` explicitly because If I don't do it. The response returns that it is missing. So I set it.

**N2:** The path for the file `/scripts/wordpress/240p.mp4` is correct. Permissions too.

**N3:** I'm aware of the remote upload feature, but I need to upload from binary files (from local I mean)

**N4:** Pretty obvious but `self.r` is the assignment of a `requests.session()`

Comment: use https://github.com/mohan3d/PyOpenload

Comment: I'm gonna try it. Thanks. If it works I'm gonna inspect the code to know where is my code failing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it wasn't working.
The problem was solved by letting `requests` handle the `content-type`header.
The value of `name`variable in the multipart field is irrelevant, you can call it `file1`, `file_upload` or whatever.

This is working for me:

```
filepath = '/scripts/wordpress/240p.mp4'

sha1 = hashlib.sha1()

BLOCKSIZE = 65536
with open(filepath, 'rb') as afile:
    buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
    while len(buf) > 0:
        sha1.update(buf)
        buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)

sha1_hash = sha1.hexdigest()

url = "https://api.openload.co/1/file/ul?login={login}&key={key}&sha1={sha1}".format(
    login='YOUR_LOGIN',
    key='YOUR_API_KEY',
    sha1=sha1_hash,
)

p = {
    'url': url,
    'headers': {
        'User-Agent': self.ua,
    }
}
r = self.r.get(url=p['url'], headers=p['headers'])
j = r.json()

upload_link = j['result']['url']

p = {
    'url': upload_link,
    'headers': {
        'user-agent': self.ua,
    },
    'files': {
        'file1': open(filepath, 'rb'),
    }
}
r = self.r.post(url=p['url'], headers=p['headers'], files=p['files'])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code.....for uploading file using openload api.

first get folder id using this url

```html
https://api.openload.co/1/file/listfolder?login=XXXXXXX&key=XXXX
```

after getting folder id add folder id,login,key to below code..that's it.

```html
<html>
  <form action="demo3.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <input type="file" name="file">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="upload">
  </form>

  <?php
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.openload.co/1/file/ul?login=XXXXXXXXX&key=XXXXXXX&folder=3994051');
   // Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   // Get the response and close the channel.
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   $json=json_decode($response);
   $url=$json->result->url;

   curl_close($ch);
   if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
   {
    
    $ch1=curl_init();
    $cfile=new CURLFile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file']['name']);
    $cfile->setPostFilename(basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    $data=array("file"=>$cfile);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response1=curl_exec($ch1);
    $json1=json_decode($response1);
    echo $json1->result->url;
    echo $response1;
    curl_close($ch1);
    #echo $json1;
   }
  ?>
</html>
```